# SonarQube session timeout

Tags: github, authentication, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

We are using the Github Login plugin, and we wanted to increase the length of user's sessions in sonarqube. I've added the following configuration

```
sonar.web.sessionTimeoutInMinutes=43200
```

but now the Github Login doesn't work. It just redirects to the login form every time you login. We are currently using Sonarqube 6.2, with the following plugins:

- sonar-scm-git-plugin
- sonar-java-plugin
- sonar-github-plugin
- sonar-auth-github-plugin
- qualinsight-plugins-sonarqube-badges
- sonar-android
- sonar-csharp-plugin
- sonar-python-plugin

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got [an answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/increase$20user$20session%7Csort:relevance/sonarqube/ZTu4yNnBx2s/1gO6PhK3BQAJ):

> There is a bug in SonarQube 6.3 and the maximum accepted value for this property is 35791: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/FPnOX-N8G34/jHNJXOOFBwAJ

Reducing that number fixed the issue